# Modify header value based on dynamic header key in NGINX proxy pass

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

We have a header key that vary with a dynamic number "Name-**123**", the prefix is static.

The issue we are facing is that we need to delete only the headers with the prefix "Name-", everything else must be passed.

We use the code below which is currently passing the full header.

```
location ~* ^/(es-la)/? {
      set $sl_stream $scheme://our-proxy-url.com;
      proxy_pass $sl_stream;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: If you know which headers the upstream server uses, you could disable all headers and only send those that are needed.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks but unfortunately, we don't know and it can change as the application starts to be upgraded.